# Transpose Function in R Changes Values Unexpectedly

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe that I need to transpose

```
                      A                 B
4                   4024               4796
5                   4130               4796
6                   4130               4796
7                   4130               4796
8                   4067               4687
9                   4067               4687
```

When I use t(df), I get the following output.

```
        4             5             6             7             8
A 1.988120e-320 2.040491e-320 2.040491e-320 2.040491e-320 2.009365e-320
B 2.369539e-320 2.369539e-320 2.369539e-320 2.369539e-320 2.315686e-320
        9
A 2.009365e-320
B 2.315686e-320
```

Why are the values changing?

Comment: I've seen something similar to this. It had to do with the kind of integer it was stored as, though in the end I didn't find out for sure

Comment: My values are currently of type double

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted a sample of your data in R code (just use the dput function)

Answer (score 1):

An option wuld be to `gather` the 'A', 'B' column to 'long' format after creating a column from row names, then `spread` to 'wide' format and change the 'key' column to row name

```
library(tidyverse)
rownames_to_column(df1, 'rn') %>% 
  gather(key, val, A:B) %>% 
  spread(rn, val) %>%
  column_to_rownames('key')
#    4    5    6    7    8    9
#A 4024 4130 4130 4130 4067 4067
#B 4796 4796 4796 4796 4687 4687
```

---

The reason why values are changing is because the columns are `factor` and by transposing, it is converted to `matrix`, where the `factor` values get changed to integer encoded value

An option would be to first convert the columns to `character`, then to `integer` (if needed) and do the transpose

```
t(sapply(df1, function(x) as.integer(as.character(x))))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c(4024L, 4130L, 4130L, 4130L, 4067L, 4067L
), B = c(4796L, 4796L, 4796L, 4796L, 4687L, 4687L)), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c("4",
 "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"))
```